# Django: What is the best way to update multiple model instances simultaneously through a web interface?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a django template that lists model instances and their attributes in a table.  One of the attributes is a choice field with a pulldown of the choices.  I am currently trying to figure the best way to handle updates to that field.  Is there a way to let the user change the instances they want and do a bulk submit?  Or should have it autosubmit on something like an onChange event for each instance individually?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for Django's [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), which allow you to group together multiple forms and then handle them in bulk. In this case I'm assuming that each model instance would be a model form and therefore part of the formset.

Without code examples I can't provide suggestions on how you might implement them, but the documentation should take you most of the way there.

Comment: Nice, I think this might be exactly what I am looking for.